# xml.etree.ElementTree >> Python >> How to access child element and make assertions

Tags: python-3.x, xml, pytest, elementtree

I am using PyTest to validate xml api response.
Getting following response(response.content) from api request

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Result0>
<Result1>
<Result3>
<Id>2</Id>
<ItemId>https://purchanse.com/62/E00036415</ItemId>
<Place>kpi:62_CS415-TEN-1080p25-ABC</Place>
<Marks>12</Marks>
<SubId>9, 8</SubId>
<Description>https://purchanse.com/62/E00036416</Description>
</Result3>
<Result4>
<Id>2</Id>
<ItemId>https://purchanse.com/64/E00036417</ItemId>
<Place>kpi:63_CS415-TEN-1080p25-XYZ</Place>
<Marks>12</Marks>
<SubId>9</SubId>
<Description>https://purchanse.com/64/E00036416</Description>
</Result4>
</Result1>
</Result0>'
```

in test function I have this code

```
def test_CheckResponseContent():
    element = et.fromstring(response.content)
    print("element", element)  # Getting <Element 'Result0' at 0x04A88C58> as output
    links = element.find("Result0/Result1")
    print("L:", links)  # Returns 'None'

element = et.fromstring(response.content)
    for child in element.iter('*'):
        print(child.tag)
```

I want to make assertions like

```
Marks == 12
Id == 2
ItemId != "https://purchanse.com/62/E00036416"
```

How can I parse the XML for this?
Can someone please help

Comment: Use XPath queries, e.g. `assert element.find('.//Result1/Result3/Marks').text == '12'` etc. You are starting in `Result0`, so all queries are made relative to the `Result0` node.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650249/hoefling Thanks a ton. And is there any way to check that in loop and mark assert as 'fail', if condition not met in any of node. Like if, I want to check SubId == 9 in all child nodse. So it should fail as in 1st child node we have <SubId>9, 8</SubId>

Comment: `element.findall('.//Result1//SubId')` will give you a list of all `SubId` elements that are located in the subtree of `Result1`. From there, you can assert in a loop or do smth like `assert all(el.text == '9' for el in element.findall('.//Result1//SubId'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **multiple** tags with mentioned names, so the corresponding
set of checks should be performed **separately**, for each parent of
these tags.

To do it, try the following code, maybe without *print* statements:

```
for it in element.findall('Result1/*'):
    print(it.tag)
    mrks = it.findtext('Marks')
    id = it.findtext('Id')
    itmId = it.findtext('ItemId')
    print(mrks, id, itmId)
    assert mrks == '12'
    assert id == '2'
    assert itmId != 'https://purchanse.com/62/E00036416'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7388477/valdi-bo Thanks. Actually this is what I was looking for. But somehow I am not able to print those statements (which I wanted to see). And In addition to that is there any way to check itemIds present in the list using contains or using OR. Like ```assert itmId != purchanse.com/62/E00036416 or purchanse.com/62/E00036417 or purchanse.com/62/E00036416`` assert itmId contains https://purchanse.com/62/E00036416, https://purchanse.com/62/E00036417, https://purchanse.com/62/E00036416

Comment: First try my code on just **the same** input data sample which you included in your post. If my code prints the required data, you have a proof that it is OK.
If this code does not print expected results on **other** input data, then
probably this (other) data is in some respect different and you should identify this
difference.
And as far as other conditions are concerned: My code first reads the content
of each element. Then, having the content in respective variables, you can check
whatever you want, including OR of particular conditions.